# Is there anyway I can get the desired exit value from PsExec in C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, psexec, errorlevel

This is the command I am currently using for remote installation using psExec.

psExec \\MyRemoteComputer -s -c MyInstallationFile.exe /q

When I issue this command in Command Prompt Window, it works fine. If MyRemoteComputer cannot be reached, it returns error. After that, when I check the exit code with "echo %errorlevel%", it returns 53, which is correct exit code.

I coded with C# using Process like this..

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = ".....psExec.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ".....";
startInfo.Arguments = @"\\MyRemoteComputer -s -c MyInstallationFile.exe /q";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
....
proc.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(proc.ExitCode);
```

It runs fine..but..when I checked the ExitCode(Obviously, when myRemoteComputer cannot be reached), it was 6, which is other than 53.
It is sort of making sense why it is happening, but is there any way I can retrieve the 53 value, NOT 6?

I tried a couple of things..

1. cmd /c psExec.exe ....
2. created a batch file, then output %errorlevel% as a file inside that batch file...then I used this batch file in my ProcessStartInfo....
3. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable

None of them worked at all...I can't get my desired return value at all in the code...
There is really no way to retrieve the value I want??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " It is sort of making sense why it is happening" Why's that, then?

Comment: check this [thread](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic10826.html) At a glance I think this should be the issue.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I believe(am guessing) that the Process is returning the exit code from psExec, not actual one that had been run?...as u might know, psExec runs some service at the remote machine in order to communicate with....Well..but I am not quite sure why I got the correct exit code in Command Prompt window though.

Comment: @npocmaka, thanks for the link, but this is not the parameter issue.

Comment: If it is returning 6 then that is the error not 53. Your question is stupid. "how can I get a wrong exit code when running a program". This is how `set errorlevel=53`. Perhaps you might change it to "why does my program error differently when run in a batch?".

Comment: net helpmsg 6

The handle is invalid.

Comment: @noodles, was my question stupid? Well it could be...hope your comment is not...I guess I need to get the 53 specifically in this project, that is why I guess I said "correct" in this context..well..Perhaps you might need to say "I need to learn how to comment better way"...

Comment: Ok.I finally figured out this issue. Anyway, thanks for all of them who read this issue. BTW, @Noodles, I guess your comment turns out to be sxxxid.